# Automatically access to home page after register

Tags: jsp, servlets, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a register form where a user fill required fields to have and account. Once he submit he will be redirected to the login page where he should enter his login and password to access to the home page

**register form**

```
<h:form id="newCustomerForm"  >
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Register Form</legend>
                    <table border="0" >
                        <tbody >                        
                            <tr type="text">
                                <td>
                                    <p:outputLabel  value="Account Login :" for="pseudo"/>    
                                </td>
                                <p:spacer height="5px" />
                                <td>
                                    <p:inputText id="pseudo" value="#{customerMB.login}" title="Pseudo" required="true" requiredMessage="The Pseudo field is required.">

                                    </p:inputText>
                                    <p:watermark for="pseudo" value="Login" />  
                                    <p:message for="pseudo"  display="text"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <p:spacer height="5px" />  
                            <tr type="password">

                                <td>
                                    <p:outputLabel  value="Password :" for="pwd1"/>
                                </td>
                                <p:spacer height="5px" />
                                <td>
                                    <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{customerMB.password}" feedback="true" match="pwd2" label="Password 1" required="true" requiredMessage="The Password field is required."/>  
                                    <p:watermark for="pwd1" value="Password" />  
                                    <p:message for="pwd1"/>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <p:spacer height="5px" /> 
                            <tr type="password">
                                <td>
                                    <p:outputLabel  value="Confirm password :" for="pwd2"/>
                                </td>
                                <p:spacer height="5px" />
                                <td>
                                    <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{customerMB.password}" feedback="true" label="Password 2" required="true" requiredMessage="The confirm password field is required."/>  
                                    <p:watermark for="pwd2" value="Confirm Password" />  
                                    <p:message for="pwd2"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <p:spacer height="5px" />         
                            <tr type="text">
                                <td>
                                    <p:outputLabel  value="Email address :" for="email"/>
                                </td>
                                <p:spacer height="5px" />
                                <td>
                                    <p:inputText id="email" value="#{customerMB.email}"  title="Email" required="true" validatorMessage="Insert a valid email" requiredMessage="The Email field is required.">
                                        <f:validateRegex pattern="([^.@]+)(\.[^.@]+)*@([^.@]+\.)+([^.@]+)" />
                                    </p:inputText>
                                    <p:watermark for="email" value="Email" /> 
                                    <p:message for="email"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <p:spacer height="5px" /> 

                            <tr type="text">  
                                <td>
                                    <p:outputLabel  value="First Name :" for="name"/>
                                </td>
                                <p:spacer height="5px" />
                                <td>
                                    <p:inputText id="name" value="#{customerMB.name}" title="Name" required="true" requiredMessage="The Name field is required." styleClass="error"/>
                                    <p:watermark for="name" value="First Name" />  
                                    <p:message for="name"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <p:spacer height="5px" />
                            <tr type="text">
                                <td>
                                    <p:outputLabel  value="Last Name :" for="familyName"/>
                                </td>
                                <p:spacer height="5px" />
                                <td>
                                    <p:inputText id="familyName" value="#{customerMB.familyName}" title="FamilyName" required="true" requiredMessage="The FamilyName field is required."/>                                                         
                                    <p:watermark for="familyName" value="Last Name" />  
                                    <p:message for="familyName"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <p:spacer height="5px" />
                            <tr type="text">
                                <td>
                                    <p:outputLabel  value="Organization :" for="organisation"/>
                                </td>
                                <p:spacer height="5px" />
                                <td>
                                    <p:inputText id="organisation" value="#{customerMB.organisation}" title="Organisation" required="true" requiredMessage="The Organisation field is required."/>
                                    <p:watermark for="organisation" value="Organisation" />   
                                    <p:message for="organisation"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div type="submit" align="right" style="margin-top: 5px">

                        <p:commandButton style="margin-right: 20px" id="loginInput" value="Save" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-circle-check" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" binding="#{customerMB.loginInput}" action="#{customerMB.addCustomer()}" >
                            <h:message for="loginInput" style="color: red;"/>                   
                        </p:commandButton>                                                    
                        <p:commandButton  value="Cancel" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n" onclick="location.href = 'login.jsp';"  process="@this"  >  
                            <p:resetInput target="newCustomerForm" />  
                        </p:commandButton> 

                    </div>  
                </fieldset>    

            </h:form>
```

**login.jsp**

```
 <form method="POST" action="Authentication">

                    <h2>Login <img style="margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 2px" src="pictures/idp-icon.png" width="100" height="38" alt="idp-icon"/></h2>

                    <p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Login"></p>
                    <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
                    <button type="submit"></button>
                    <% String erreur = (String) request.getAttribute("erreur");
                        if (erreur != null) {%>
                    <h3 align="center" style="color: #FB0008; font-size: inherit"> Incorrect Login/Password, try again</h3>
                    <%    }%>
                    <form>
```

My objectif is how to redirect the user ,after subbmitting the form, either to the home page or to the login page with filled login and password( no need to re enter them manually)
Any idea?

Comment: `<% response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); return; %>`

Comment: You do NOT want to fill in the password in the login form. That would be exposing the user's password.  You might go ahead and set a session parameter to show them as logged in before redirecting, however.

Comment: You mean if login credential is ok then redirect it to home page otherwise redirect him to login page and set the username and password in the respective field which he entered? If it is so then you can save username and password as request attribute like request.setAttribute("username",userNameString); and get it on login page again <%= (String)request.getAttribute("username") %>